# Yanking lines from a multiple selection

Tags: cut-copy-paste, multiple-lines

I’m using the [multiselect](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953) plugin. I have selected multiple contiguous blocks of code and want to yank all of them into one register. For example, from

```
-- selected A --
—— unselected ——
-- selected B --
```

I want to have

```
-- selected A --
-- selected B --
```

in one register. Executing `MSExecCmd yank` yanks the contiguous blocks into separate registers.

So how can I yank them into one?

Comment: In which registers does the plugin store your blocks of code ? I don't know if it solves your problem, but let's say the 3 registers a, b and c contain data that you want to merge into the register d. To do so, you can type `let @d=@a.@b.@c`. The dot is an operator that concatenates strings.

Comment: saginaw: Didn’t know that, nice. Thanks! But it doesn’t *really* solve my problem because I have like 20 blocks to yank.

Comment: I don't know how your plugin works, but here's how I would do it without the plugin.

Add a mapping in my `~/.vimrc` that maps `<leader>c` to `"Ay` in visual mode, which gives : `vnoremap <leader>c "Ay`. Then, in vim clear the register `a` : `let @a=""`. Then, visually select first block of code and type `<leader>c`, go to second block of code, visually select it and type `<leader>c`, etc. When I'm finished and I want to paste the concatenated blocks, I would type in normal mode `"ap`.

Comment: Just to explain, when you use `"ay` on a visually selected text, the text overwrites the content of the register `a`, but when you use the capital letter instead of the lower one, it appends to the register instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @saginaw Thanks. You could make this into an answer. (I haven’t tried it yet, but I understand that it will work.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you run:

```
:let @a=""
:MSExecNormalCmd "Ay
```

after you have your blocks visually selected?

... the idea (even if the above doesn't work) is still to yank-append each visually selected block to the same register. But, since you use a specific plugin, *you* are the one who should know how to do it (i.e. reading the plugin's [help](https://github.com/vim-scripts/multiselect/blob/master/doc/multiselect.txt)).

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks! (About that I am the one who should know how to do it: Maybe, but in this case, I think, it’s less about the plugin and more about the logic of vim itself.)